# How to get excel header and title in Maatwebsite?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

```
Excel::load($file->getRealPath())->get();
```

This returns only items, not header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get file title with:

```
$file = Excel::load($file->getRealPath())
$file->getTitle();
```

You can also call **getTitle()** on individual sheets:

```
foreach ($file->get() as $sheet) {
  echo $sheet->getTitle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithProperties;

class InvoicesExport implements WithProperties
{    
    public function properties(): array
    {
        return [
            'creator'        => 'Patrick Brouwers',
            'lastModifiedBy' => 'Patrick Brouwers',
            'title'          => 'Invoices Export',
            'description'    => 'Latest Invoices',
            'subject'        => 'Invoices',
            'keywords'       => 'invoices,export,spreadsheet',
            'category'       => 'Invoices',
            'manager'        => 'Patrick Brouwers',
            'company'        => 'Maatwebsite',
        ];
    }
}
```

**try this**